# How to Include continuous and categorical predictors in Keras LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, forecasting

I want to use Keras LSTM (or similar) to forecast energy consumption of businesses based on:

1. historical consumption data
2. some numerical features (e.g. total yearly consumption)
3. some categorical features (e.g. business type)

This is a cold-start problem because, while 2. and 3. are present both for the training and the test set, 1. is not, i.e. I am trying to predict consumption of new businesses for which there is no historical data.

My question is: how to structure the dataframe and the RNN to accomodate both 2. (numerical features) and 3. (categorical data) as my predictors?

Here is a made-up example of the data:

```
# generate x (predictors dataframe)
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[0,1,2,3],'business_type':[0,2,2,1], 'contract_type':[0,0,2,1], 'yearly_consumption':[1000,200,300,900], 'n_sites':[9,1,2,5]})
print(x)

# note: the first 2 are categorical and the second 2 are numerical

   ID  business_type  contract_type  yearly_consumption  n_sites
0   0              0              0                1000        9
1   1              2              0                 200        1
2   2              2              2                 300        2
3   3              1              1                 900        5

# generate y (timeseries data)

import numpy as np
time_series = []
data_length = 6
period = 1
for k in range(4):
    level = 10 * np.random.rand()
    seas_amplitude = (0.1 + 0.3*np.random.rand()) * level
    sig = 0.05 * level # noise parameter (constant in time)
    time_ticks = np.array(range(data_length))
    source = level + seas_amplitude*np.sin(time_ticks*(2*np.pi)/period)
    noise = sig*np.random.randn(data_length)
    data = source + noise
    index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=t0, freq=freq, periods=data_length)
    time_series.append(pd.Series(data=data, index=['t0','t1','t2','t3','t4','t5']))
y = pd.DataFrame(time_series)
print(y)

         t0        t1        t2        t3        t4        t5
0  9.611984  8.453227  8.153665  8.801166  8.208920  8.399184
1  2.139507  2.118636  2.160479  2.216049  1.943978  2.008407
2  0.131757  0.133401  0.135168  0.141212  0.136568  0.123730
3  5.990021  6.219840  6.637837  6.745850  6.648507  5.968953

# note: the real data has thousands of data points (one year with half hourly frequency)
# note: the first row belongs to ID = 0 in x, the second row to ID = 1 etc.
```

I have looked extensively online, and there seem to be no example where both categorical, numerical and time-series data are used. For a simple forecasting problem, this [post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) explains that in order to learn from the previous time period, the LSTM must be fed something like this:

```
# process df for a classical forecasting problem for first ID
y_lstm = pd.DataFrame(y.iloc[0,:])
y_lstm.columns = ['t']
y_lstm['t-1'] = y_lstm['t'].shift()
print(y_lstm)

           t       t-1
t0  9.611984       NaN
t1  8.453227  9.611984
t2  8.153665  8.453227
t3  8.801166  8.153665
t4  8.208920  8.801166
t5  8.399184  8.208920

# note: t-1 represents the previous time point
```

However, while this works for a single timeseries, it is unclear how to structure the dataset when there are multiple timeseries, and how to include the rest of the predictors in this structure.
This [post](https://medium.com/@satnalikamayank12/on-learning-embeddings-for-categorical-data-using-keras-165ff2773fc9) talks about how to include both categorical and numerical variables through embedding, but does not fit my problem where also timeseries data has to be included. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672583/keras-categorical-vs-continuous-input-to-a-lstm) discusses between one-hot encoding and embedding without any example code and does not answer my question.

Could anyone please provide me with example code on how to structure the data appropriately for the RNN and/or how a simple LSTM structure with Keras would look like? Note that this stucture should be able to use the timeseries data for training, but not for predictions (i.e. only x and not y is available for the test set)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Were you able to find the solution? Please share. Thanks